# Merge "jabber" and "xmpp"

Tags: discussion, retag-request

[jabber](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/jabber) and [xmpp](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/xmpp) are synonyms on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). They should be synonyms on [Super User](https://superuser.com/) also.

Comment: For those unfamiliar with XMPP: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol

Comment: Maybe they should be synonyms globally on SE (except of "english.SE" maybe)?